# How to use onAvailable method in ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, wifimanager

I tried to use `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback` as follows. I no need to use `Broadcastreceivers` and only `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`. But I want to take the connected wifi `SSID` and I did as follows.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkRequest;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder().build();

        networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "*******onAvailable**********", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                WifiManager wifiManager;
                String connectedSsid = null;
                wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                connectedSsid = info.getSSID();
                if (connectedSsid != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "*******" + connectedSsid + "**********", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        };
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest,networkCallback);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
    }
}
```

I added following permissions into the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

- I registered this as `connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest,networkCallback);` inside the `onCreate` method.
- unregistered `connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);` inside `onStop` method.
  -I used `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)`. However I want to activate this task for the `Android 9`(Is this compatible for it?)

So inside the `onAvailable` method I did as follow(you can see my full code in above.)

```
WifiManager wifiManager;
String connectedSsid = null;
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
connectedSsid = info.getSSID();
if (connectedSsid != null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "*******" + connectedSsid + "**********", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So how I take the connected wifi SSID by using only `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check `WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()` and find configuration with specific network id using `WifiInfo.getNetworkId()`

For example,

In Broadcast receiver with action `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` -  retrieves current connection state from intent

> NetworkInfo nwInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
>
> nwInfo.getState()

If `NetworkInfo.getState` is equal to `NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED` then i can get current WifiInfo object

> WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
>
> WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

And then,

```
public String findSSIDForWifiInfo(WifiManager manager, WifiInfo wifiInfo) {

    List<WifiConfiguration> listOfConfigurations = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    for (int index = 0; index < listOfConfigurations.size(); index++) {
        WifiConfiguration configuration = listOfConfigurations.get(index);
        if (configuration.networkId == wifiInfo.getNetworkId()) {
            return configuration.SSID;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

NOTE: This method doesn't require Location or Location Permissions.